# How to remove black screen on launch in swift

Tags: ios, swift

> I have removed LaunchScreen.storyboard from my project and added my viewcontroller as initial view controller.
> and from project navigation i have added Launch screen file to my viewcontroller storyboard.
> [image]

how can we remove black screen when we launch our app

Answer (score 1):

Select your storyboard who has your viewcontroller in `Launch Screen File`. Then go that storyboard and check `Is Initial View Controller`. Otherwise your launch screen wont shown or shown with black screen